# geany - disable run log

Tags: geany

Geany 1.33 produces a run log in the working directory when I run a script from within the editor. (Build.Execute)

How do I disable this?

I see nothing in preferences or in the Build menu or in the Build configuration. A grep of the ~/.config/geany directory finds nothing like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ~/.config/geany/filedefs/filetypes.python file:

```
/usr/bin/python3  -i '%f'  | tee run.log
```

Replace with

```
/usr/bin/python3  -i '%f'
```

Fixes the problem.

I may have put that in myself long ago...